# Multicast in java without requiring destination hosts to join the group

Tags: java, multicast

It may be a silly question, I don't know whether it is possible or not. For examples if I have 4 servers, A, B, C and D. In the examples that I founded on the internet. If host A wants to send messages to C and D, A has to join the group, and so do C and D. My problem is sometimes, I may want A to send messages to B and C, or to C and D only. Or even B may send message to A and C or A and D later. Is there any elegant solution for this problem ?

More details:
What I want to achieve is an application, which can be able to send message to a list of other arbitrary applications. So the list will not stay the same every time. In Java, currently in order to do that via multicast, sender and receivers must join the same group. And this will need to be repeated every time the list is changed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what did you facing problem? the question confused!! please elaborate if possible.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is done by having a filter on the receiving side.  Include in the packet a list of servers to receive the message and if a server receives a message which is not for it, it ignores the message.  There are standard filtering techniques but if you need something more flexible you have to add this in code.

Answer (score 0):

> If host A wants to send messages to C and D, A has to join the group, and so do C and D

No. Only C and D have to join the group.

> My problem is sometimes, I may want A to send messages to B and C, or to C and D only. Or even B may send message to A and C or A and D later

This doesn't sound much like multicasting at all. If you have this few hosts, why not just use unicast?

> In Java, currently in order to do that via multicast, sender and receivers must join the same group.

That's not correct.

1. Java has nothing to do with it.
2. Neither does 'currently'.
3. There is no requirement for the sender to join the multicast group, or, in Java terms, to even use a `MulticastSocket` as opposed to a `DatagramSocket.`

Java just provides a class library built over IP multicast, as defined in [RFC 1112](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1112.txt) in 1989.

It seems to me that what you want can be implemented by the adroit use of *multiple* multicast groups, or perhaps multiple ports within the same multicast group.

But as presently expressed your question is a contradiction in terms.